# How to create and manage floating IP for a local highly available cluster?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, cluster-computing

I currently have a highly available cluster for multiple services of my application. The cluster is working without any problem on AWS and now I want to replicate and adapt the whole structure within a local network.

I use Pacemaker/Corosync to share AWS Elastic IP between two HAProxy instances. But I'm not sure if it is possible to create the same flow within my local network since I don't know how to share a single local IP between two of the computers.

Is it possible to manage a single local IP as a floating IP within local network?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the HAPROXY with  VRRP and Keepalived setup. I will have to do a test in my homelab if you need configs.

Comment: It would be great to have it. Meanwhile, I will also look into and test it in my local setup. Then I can verify if my configs are correct comparing them with yours. Thanks in advance! Appreciated it!

Comment: Okay I just tested and it seems it works (sort of). I have configured keepalived on two local computers with their respective local IP addresses (192.168.1.113 and 192.168.1.135) and also a random virtual IP (192.168.1.232) for VRRP. Once I start keepalived on the master node, eth interface claims virtual IP along with it's own IP. However, the slave node claims different virtual IP (192.168.1.231) once I start the keepalived. This prevents me to bind actual virtual IP 192.168.1.232 to the HAProxy configuration. Once I shutdown master haproxy, the slave takes over 192.168.1.232 and just works.